# SSRS: Grouping column data sorting by A to Z

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've made one grouping with "Name". Now when I retrieving the data from Dataset it shows something like this,

```
Eadadfadasdas
Masdadadad
Dadasdasdad
Sasdadadasd
Asdffff
```

I do not want to change the order In Dataset. Is it possible to do it with Expressions in SSRS Report.

I want the result like this,

```
Asdffff 
Dadasdasdad
Eadadfadasdas
Masdadadad
Sasdadadasd
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSRS table (which I assume you are displaying this data in)  YOu need to sort by the Fieldname as follows

1. Right click the Row Header and click Row Group -> Group Properties
2. Then select the Sort Tab and set the Column to sort on to be your Column Name as shown

[image]

3. This will display your data in alphabetical order

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Group Properties for 'Name'.

Under the Sorting tab, sort by name A-Z.

Comment: I've already checked this, but still it is not sorting the data.

Comment: Gah, sorry @bushell, I've just seen you've already answered this while I was writing my answer.  If you're not offended I shall leave my answer though as it includes the pictures.

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal - Can you clarify what your table sorting is if it's still not behaving as expected?  Can you add a link to a picture to your original question?

Comment: In that case, I would open the rdl file in notepad, and look through the XML for the group properties.  There will be a tag for <SortExpressions>.